# Order one list and have the other list change order so the index of both lists still match

Tags: python, list

I have two lists asking for user input that are names and scores, so they relate to each other but aren't connected in any way.

I want to either order by name or score, but if I order either, the name and score doesn't match.

How would I be able to order one list and change the order of the other list so the score for a person is the same as their name?

This is my full code:

```
test_scores =  []
names = []


while -1 not in test_scores:
    print()
    test_scores.append(int(input("Enter test score:  ")))
    names.append(input("Enter students name:   "))
    
  
test_scores = test_scores[:-1] 
print ()

print(names, test_scores )

order = input("How do you want to order the list? N for by name or S for by score:   ")

if order == "S" or order == "s":
    test_scores = sorted(test_scores, reverse=True) 
elif order == "N" or order == "n":
    names = sorted(names, reverse=False)

print(names, test_scores )

index = 0
for count in range (len(test_scores)):
    print(f"{names[index]} got {test_scores[index]}")
    index+=1
```

Comment: Use a different data structure to store your data. Names & scores are linked so they should be together. A dict with name -> score mapping would be something easier to work with.

Comment: Use a level of indirection. Instead of sorting your lists, create a third list `list(range(len(names)))` of indexes and sort that.

Comment: @rdas I'd usually agree, but a `dict` is an unordered data structure, so this is not 100% applicable here. An `OrderedDict` might be an alternative

Comment: @code-lukas no, `dict` objects are ordered since Python 3.7 (and as an implementation detail in 3.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in Python is to use tuples. Tuples join two other objects together. For example: `(99, 'Hanaa')`

Also, the zip function can be useful for creating tuples because it 'zips' two lists together:

```
results = list(zip(test_scores, names))
print(results)

[(99, 'Hanaa'), (85, 'Hans')]
```

The neat thing about tuples is they are comparable using the usual conditional operators:

```
print((99, 'Hanaa') > (85, 'Hans'))

True
```

This means you can sort a list of tuples:

```
results.sort()
print(results)

[(85, 'Hans'), (99, 'Hanaa')]
```

Items are sorted according to the first item first, and if that is equal, then it sorts by the second item.

If you want to sort by the second item (name in this example), you either have to rebuild the list of tuples with the item positions swapped or use the key argument in the sort function:

```
score_sort_key = lambda x: x[0]
name_sort_key = lambda x: x[1]

print(sorted(results, key=name_sort_key))

[(99, 'Hanaa'), (85, 'Hans')]

print(sorted(results, key=score_sort_key))

[(85, 'Hans'), (99, 'Hanaa')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you remove the `-1` from the `test_scores` list but not remove the name of the student who gets the marks `-1`.

ADD `names=names[:-1]`

Try this.

```
test_scores =  []
names = []


while -1 not in test_scores:
    print()
    test_scores.append(int(input("Enter test score:  ")))
    names.append(input("Enter students name:   "))
    
  
test_scores = test_scores[:-1] 
names = names[:-1]
print ()

print(names, test_scores )

order = input("How do you want to order the list? N for by name or S for by score:   ")

if order == "S" or order == "s":
    test_scores = sorted(test_scores, reverse=True) 
elif order == "N" or order == "n":
    names = sorted(names, reverse=False)

print(names, test_scores )

index = 0
for count in range (len(test_scores)):
    print(f"{names[index]} got {test_scores[index]}")
    index+=1
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter test score:  15
Enter students name:   SHA

Enter test score:  16
Enter students name:   QQQ

Enter test score:  -1
Enter students name:   AAA

['SHA', 'QQQ'] [15, 16]
How do you want to order the list? N for by name or S for by score:   N
['QQQ', 'SHA'] [15, 16]
QQQ got 15
SHA got 16
```